# Soundcloud track comments ordered by timestamp

Tags: comments, soundcloud

Is there a way to get `/tracks/{id}/comments` for a track ordered by `timestamp asc/desc`? The default order is by `created_at` property descending.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if soundcloud offers the possibility to sort the requests, but you can sort the response of the request whit [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strnatcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) for natural order string.
Like this:

```
function orderBy($data, $field) { 
        $code = "return strnatcmp(\$a['$field'], \$b['$field']);";
        usort($data, create_function('$a,$b', $code)); 
        return $data; 
} 

// Get comments
$comments = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks/{id_track}/comments'), true);

// Order comments by 'timestamp'
$data = orderBy($comments, 'timestamp');
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but i was looking for answer from someone from soundcloud. 
they are returning 50 comments per page, and I don't want to fetch all the comments and then to sort them. but at the end, maybe that will be the only solution.

Comment: however, you can do it with function for()

Comment: i will do it with javascript. the idea was to get the results in order as i need them, not to get all pages. i don't want to overload the server, if there is other solution.